# RedirectAttributes not working with Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am on a Spring Webflux application, and I want to perform a redirection on one of my controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    @GetMapping
    public String loginView(final Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("authenticationForm", new AuthenticationForm());

        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Rendering authenticate(@Valid final AuthenticationForm authenticationForm,
                                  final BindingResult bindingResult, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            final AccountDto authenticatedAccount =
                    this.authenticationFacade.authenticate(authenticationForm).block();

            if (authenticatedAccount != null) {
                return Rendering.redirectTo("/home").build();
            }
        }

        return Rendering.view("login").build();
    }
}
```

I know that Rendering.redirectTo() performs the redirection as a RedirectView. However, when I add the RedirectAttributes in my controller method parameters to provide redirection attributes, I have the following exception:

```
2017-09-28 18:35:08.084 ERROR 3702 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : Failed to handle request

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to invoke handler method with resolved arguments: [0][type=org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareConcurrentModel][value={}],[1][type=org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareConcurrentModel][value={}] on public java.lang.String fr.auchan.wheatley.front.controller.AuthenticationController.loginView(org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1010)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenCoordinator.signal(MonoWhen.java:246)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenInner.onNext(MonoWhen.java:306)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1567)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenInner.onSubscribe(MonoWhen.java:296)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:173)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:2769)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenCoordinator.subscribe(MonoWhen.java:177)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen.subscribe(MonoWhen.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:147)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:148)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:270)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:790)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1567)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:156)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1381)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1255)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:2769)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:414)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:91)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:2769)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:2769)
    at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter.service(ServletHttpHandlerAdapter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's my configuration:
- Spring Boot 2.0.0.M3 (Spring 5.0.0.RC3).
- Spring Webflux

Is it impossible to provide redirection attributes this way with Spring 5? Is there another way to do it, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes`, a Spring MVC class - in Spring WebFlux. This isn't going to work.

I'm not aware of any equivalent for that in WebFlux, this could be an enhancement request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed we should be able to redirect with attributes in Spring Webflux. I opened a JIRA to ask for the improvement: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16026

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure about how this works in Spring 5. However, fundamentally, when you redirect to a different URL, it becomes a fresh request to the HTTP server. That means, the server expects all required attributes and parameters in the new redirected request in order to access that.

I think, this is what the issue here in your case, where your controller expects a parameter that is getting lost because of this new request generated using redirection. Try to find a way to forward this request, instead of redirection. That will carry all the original attributes in the request for your end controller.

I am not sure, if I could understand the issue correctly and could throw any light on this issue resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, when I add the RedirectAttributes parameter to my controller method, the code doesn't even reach the redirection, it throws the exception directly whenever the method is called. As Brian mentioned in his answer, it seems due to the fact that the RedirectAttributes class is not available in Spring Webflux at the moment. I opened a JIRA at Spring to ask for the improvement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answers, the *RedirectAttributes* equivalent doesn't seems to exist in Spring Webflux at the moment.

I opened a JIRA at Spring to ask for the improvement, here's the link if some people are interested in getting updates on that point too: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16026